# Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or because access is denied

Tags: active-directory

I was getting message on laptop upon trying to get laptop to accept updated windows password (I updated my password on another desktop machine, not the laptop):

"User cant change password: Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or because access is denied"

I wondered how to resolve this message?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I could resolve this by:

turning off Wifi ..
turning WIFI back on and connecting with new password.
Windows then prompted me to lock and unlock Windows session to update credentials.